# OpenCV causes Segmentation Fault sometimes at imshow (R PI / Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I have a code that handles images in a loop and works perfectly fine in 999 of the cases. Every now and then it collapses with an error something like this:

```
(Window: 18832): Gdk-CRITICAL **:12:44:27.666: gdk_device_get_n_axes: assertation GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

The number of error lines and the wording varies, the GDK_IS_DEVICE and the Segmentation fault is always there, but some parts are changing, and sometimes it drops this message twice, sometimes much more. The error can occur with any iteration, sometimes it happens right away, sometimes days later with the 1210.cycle or more.

The part where the program exists always is where I show a new picture on the display with imread, then imshow.

The code is in Python, and the environment is a Raspberry Pi 4

Is there a method to debug somehow these errors? Maybe there are some logs, where I can find some clues?

Comment: Check if you have enough memory

Comment: I checked, every resource is ok, load is pretty low. I'm clueless...